# Spring Security 5 OAuth2 WebClient [client_authorization_required] Authorization required for Client Registration Id: dummies"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement a simple example following this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N-xwmoN83w&t=1653s
and this: https://github.com/jzheaux/messaging-app

I am running a local OAuth2 Server using spring boot (@EnableAuthorizationServer) and I can take a token with this /oauth/token and check the token with /oauth/check_token.

I created an application (APP_CORE) with spring boot (@EnableResourceServer) and protected endpoints (/key-value, /products, etc). Only with the token, the user can access the services.

But now I have another application (APP_01) and I want to pass the token from APP_01 to APP_CORE.

I can access whatever endpoint in APP_01 using the token, but when I am trying to access a method that tries to access another endpoint in APP_CORE using WebClient I receive this:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1550727169951,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "[client_authorization_required] Authorization required for Client Registration Id: dummies",
    "trace": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationRequiredException: [client_authorization_required] Authorization required for Client Registration Id: dummies\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.method.annotation.OAuth2AuthorizedClientArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(OAuth2AuthorizedClientArgumentResolver.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:86)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n",
    "path": "/questionnaire/key-value/dummies"
}
```

**application.yml**

```
  spring:  
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          dummies:
            client-id: fooClientIdPassword
            client-secret: secret
            provider: oauthserver
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:7001
            scope: read,write,foo
        provider:
          oauthserver:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:7777/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost:7777/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:7777/user
            token-info-uri: http://localhost:7777/oauth/check_token
            user-info-authentication-method: basic
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:7777/token_keys
```

**WebSecurity**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2_console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .authorizationRequestResolver(customAuthorizationRequestResolver())
                .and()
                    .tokenEndpoint()
                        .accessTokenResponseClient(customAccessTokenResponseClient())
                .and()
                .and()
                .oauth2Client();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
    }


    private OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver customAuthorizationRequestResolver() {
        return new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(this.clientRegistrationRepository);
    }

    private OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> customAccessTokenResponseClient() {
        OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter =
                new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();
        tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter.setTokenResponseConverter(new CustomAccessTokenResponseConverter());

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(
                new FormHttpMessageConverter(), tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter));
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());

        DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient tokenResponseClient = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
        tokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate);

        return tokenResponseClient;
    }

}
```

**Service method**

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/dummies"})
public List<String> dummies(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("dummies") OAuth2AuthorizedClient dummiesClient, Map<String, Object> model) {
        return this.getDummies(dummiesClient);
    }

    private List<String> getDummies(OAuth2AuthorizedClient dummiesClient) {

        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
        };

        return this.webClient
                .get()
                .uri("http://localhost:6666/dummy-service/dummies")
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(dummiesClient))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(typeRef)
                .block();
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure out why this is? I'm getting the same issue currently.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same Exception `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationRequiredException` and I found that the cause of this problem in my case is

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public String exception(RuntimeException e) {
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```

And I solved the problem in this way :

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public String exception(RuntimeException e) {
        if (e instanceof ClientAuthorizationRequiredException) { 
            throw e;
        }
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```

In the place where the exception was thrown `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizationCodeOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider#authorize`, a comment was written--

```
// ClientAuthorizationRequiredException is caught by
// OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter which initiates authorization
```

I think this may mean that the exception must be caught by `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter`

Comment: If I could give +100 for this. I'd be much obliged